# Run multiple nginx on one dedicated server ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, memory, nginx

Is it possible to run multiple NGINX on a single Dedicated server?
I have a dedicated server with 256gb of ram, and I am running multiple PHP scripts on it but it's getting hangs because of memory used with PHP.
when I check

```
free -m
```

it's not even using 1% of memory.

So, I am guessing its has some to do with NGINX.

Can I install multiple NGINX on this server and use them like

```
 5.5.5.5:8080,  5.5.5.5:8081,  5.5.5.5:8082
```

I have already allocated 20 GB memory to PHP, but still not working Properly.

Reason :- NGINX gives 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: Out of pure interest, why do you want to run more than one webserver?

Comment: I'd suggest tracking down the memory errors. 20GB is a lot of memory, so there's another issue going on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly because one NGINX gives 504 error....

Comment: Do you know what a 404 error is?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry its 504 error

Comment: You get a timeout when the script takes longer than 30 seconds (by default, configurable). It is not related to memory. When PHP script dies because of memory allocation it is 500 error.

Comment: @AlexBlex I know that, i have 2 pages on same server, 1 running script and another is just echo 'HI' in it both are giving time out, so i thing is memory issue.

Comment: Ah, and it doesn't matter how many nginx instancess you are running. A single nginx can work with multiple fpm pools, and each pool can have multiple workers.

Comment: I doubt the "Hi" script requires more than 20GB of RAM.

Comment: @AlexBlex i know that, but hi page is also not loading .... why ?

Comment: If all your scripts result with the same error, it must be nginx cannot connect to php-fpm, or php-fpm have no workers, or any other misconfiguration. I haven't seen your configs to say for sure. Check logs.

Comment: @AlexBlex ya i know, so if I install 2 NGINX and 2 PHP it will work, because script 2 is running every minute and putting load on server.

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to achieve by instantiating multiple servers. It really sounds like and XY problem. squared. What was the original issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Either PHP or NGINX is misconfigured**

You may run multiple instances of nginx on the same server provided that some conditions are met. But this is not the solution you should look for (also this may not solve your problem at all).

Answer (score 0):

I got my Ubuntu / PHP / Nginx server set this way (it actually also runs some Node.js servers in parallel). Here is a configuration example which works fine on a AWS EC2 medium instance (m3).

```
upstream xxx {
#   server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
    ip_hash;
    keepalive 512;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;
    listen 443 ssl;
    #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name xxx.mydomain.io yyy.mydomain.io;
    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http' ) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    root /home/ubuntu/www/xxxroot;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }


    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        #allow 1.2.3.4#your-ip;
        #deny all;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass adn;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
#fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /xxxroot/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
#fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/ubuntu/www/xxxroot;
        # send bad requests to 404
        #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a timeout. Your PHP-Scripts seams to run to long.

Check following:

- `max_execution_time` in your php.ini
- `request_terminate_timeout` in `www.conf` of your PHP-FPM configuration
- `fastcgi_read_timeout` in `http` section or `location` section of your nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is designed more to be used as a reverse proxy or load balancer than to control application logic and run php scripts. Running multiple instances of nginx that each execute php isn't really playing to the server application's strengths. As an alternative, I'd recommend using nginx to proxy between one or more apache instances, which are better suited to executing heavy php scripts. http://kbeezie.com/apache-with-nginx/ contains information on getting apache and nginx to play nicely together.